# Moving Auto generated User MVC 4 mdf file over to SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 project which has an auto generated `.mdf` SQL Server database file attached to it. I have also attached a SQL Server database to the web application as well.

I want to move that user `.MDF` file since it already has the prefixes I need, into the SQL Server. However when I do this and modify the changes (see below) I always get an exception thrown from the membership `initialize.cs` saying the database couldn't be initialized. Sorry if it's a bit vague but its a real head scratcher to explain. I will provide info upon further request :)

`Account.cs`:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext() : base("MyDatabase")
    {
    }
```

`Membership.cs`:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyDatabase", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
}
```

Connection string in `web.config`:

```
<add name="MyDatabase" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.data.csdl|res://*/Models.data.ssdl|res://*/Models.data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=GOLDENEYE\SHELDON;initial catalog=JobTracker-Security;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further trial and error found that the connection string needed authentication to the SQL Server....it also needed the added integrity security as well :) i appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Is 'GOLDENEYE' the name of your machine ?
and SHELDON your SQLServer instance name ?
in that case did you try with :

> data source=SHELDON;

Comment: that breaks the connection of the sql server im afraid :)